# SQL 2000 equivalent of SQLAgentReaderRole

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have quite a few developers asking me if certain SQL jobs ran, and I would like to give them access to check it on their own without giving them `sysadmin` rights.  I know that in `SQL 2005`, you can grant them the `SQLAgentReaderRole`, but I am looking for a solution in `SQL 2000`.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure there isn't one out of the box.  This thread seems to be pretty decent...halfway down they discuss creating a role and then locking that down further.  Also you could just create a mini-program (sp even?) to email the results of the job as a summary, or add to each job an on completion event to email an email group.

http://sqlforums.windowsitpro.com/web/forum/messageview.aspx?catid=60&threadid=43021&enterthread=y

Comment: Correct, there's no such role for SQL 2000.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's some hope for those of us still working with 2000 -

"In order to accomplish this in SQL Server 2000 the DBA must add the user to TargetServersRole role in MSDB database. Prior to Service Pack 3 on SQL Server 2000 the user must be added to the sysadmin group in order to get a chance to view the jobs that are owned by sysadmin group."

Quoted from http://www.sql-server-performance.com/faq/sqlagent_scheduled_jobs_p1.aspx via http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/8a05fe47-50c7-4b95-b631-8f7d69d31dae